# Convert an array directly to an image (each cell becomes one pixel) in python

Tags: python, data-representation

I want to convert an 64x64 cell array to an 64x64 pixel image. Using matplotlib and pylab I am ending up with images that are approximately 900x900 with the extra pixels being blended together.

```
py.figure(1)
py.clf()
py.imshow( final_image , cmap='Greys_r' )
```

How do I convert from cell to pixel in a  1:1 ratio? (If you can't already tell, I'm fairly new to this).

Comment: Can you provide a better example of what you've already tried ?

Comment: What is the content of the cell array?

Answer (score 0):

That is example of using PIL to create image 2x2. a is array of colors of size 4 (flat)

```
from PIL import Image

a = [(0, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255)]

#  Create RGB image with size 2x2
img = Image.new("RGB", (2, 2))
#  Save it to the new function
img.putdata(a)
#  Save to the file
img.save('1.png')
```

You should adjust that to the format of your data if it is not flat, of course. That should be easy though. For example, this script flattens data from two-dimensional list:

```
a = [[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]], [[5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]]
a = [tuple(color) for row in a for color in row]
print a
```

If you are dealing with numpy arrays rather then lists, you should use function fromarray (in the following way):

```
#  data is numpy array
img = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')
#  Save to the file
img.save('1.png')
```

Please note that using numpy arrays is highly recommended since it is just wrapped C arrays and thus they are waay faster.